# Bitcoin.org gpg keys expired?

Tags: security

I was trying to add the keys to a keyring to verify the bitcoin core download, but it looks like the gpg keys are all expired.

Comment: Which keys specifically? Do you have a link?

Comment: @Pieter see addendum to my answer for possible/probable link.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't even considered OP might have been using bitcoin.org.

Answer (score 2):

The [home website for Bitcoin Core](https://bitcoincore.org/en/download/) says

> Refresh expired keys using:
> `gpg --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --refresh-keys`

I would obtain Bitcoin Core from that bitcoincore.org website and not from bitcoin.org.

---

For signature checking to be more meaningful as a check on authorship or correctness rather than merely a checksum of download integrity, it is probably important to obtain your GPG public keys from a source that is as independent as possible from the website from which you download the source or binaries. Otherwise you could download doctored code and faked signatures & keys from a hacked or impostor website.  This independence appears to be the case with software from bitcoincore.org and keys from openpgp.org or elsewhere (if I understand correctly).

---

You are correct that bitcoin.org currently (2022-02-17) has old expired keys.

After visiting https://bitcoin.org/en/download and clicking "Bitcoin Core Release Signing Keys" [v0.11.0+](https://bitcoin.org/laanwj-releases.asc) I also see an expired key.

```
C> gpg --import laanwj-releases.asc
gpg: key 36C2E964: public key "Wladimir J. van der Laan (Bitcoin Core binary release signing key) <laanwj@gmail.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found

C> gpg --list-keys
----------------------------------------------
pub   4096R/36C2E964 2015-06-24 [expired: 2022-02-10]
uid                  Wladimir J. van der Laan (Bitcoin Core binary release signing key) <laanwj@gmail.com>
```